# SQL Server: can I restore full DB file backup to First LSN (i.e. when backup started)?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, transaction-log, checkpoint

A full database backup was started at 15:46:00 using the following cmd:

```
backup database IF_BROWNS to disk = 'C:\temp\IF_STDINT_{0}.BAK' (where {0} = timestamp, e.g. 2017-05-16T15-46-00.0831634+01-00)
```

The IF_BROWNS database was in Full recovery mode at the time. The backup took 34 seconds to complete. There are no other backups (full, differential or log) available.

I want to restore the database to the earliest point in time possible, i.e. 15:46:00. This [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/full-database-backups-sql-server) implies that that the backup will normally be restored to the database's state at the end of the backup, i.e. 15:46:34

```
     *Full database backups represent the database at the time the backup finished.*
```

I tried using the Timeline button on the restore dialog and although it gave the impression that I could restore to 15:46:00, it did not actually make any difference to the generated restore cmd, and the restored database definitely contains data changes made after 15:46:00.

I can find articles describing how to restore to a point in time or LSN if I have a log backup, but as I said before I do not have that.

Here is an image of the restore dialog, showing times and LSNs:

[image]

Comment: See [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127492/restore-database-to-point-in-time-from-full-backup-only) answer by Aaron Bertrand.

Comment: Looks like the answer is that it can't be done ... see [Restore database to point in time from full backup only](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127492/restore-database-to-point-in-time-from-full-backup-only)